# The components of props error on react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I have a styled class component below, it define a TextInput and with Icon and placeholder two props.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, TextInput } from "react-native";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

const StyledView = styled.View`
  ...
`;

const StyledIconView = styled.View`
  ...
`;

const StyledTextInput = styled.TextInput`
  ...
`;

class LoginTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: this.props.text };
  }

  render() {
    const { Icon } = this.props;    // it seems have a problem here
    return (
      <StyledView>
        <StyledIconView>
          <Icon />                  // and here
        </StyledIconView>
        <StyledTextInput
          placeholder={this.state.text}
          onChangeText={searchString => {
            this.setState({ searchString });
          }}
        />
      </StyledView>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginTextInput;
```

And then I can use this component to customize my own case.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput } from "react-native";

import LoginTextInput from "./LoginTextInput";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import SimpleIcon from "react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons";

const UserIcon = () => <Icon name="user-o" size={20} color="#757575" />;

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: "Useless Placeholder" };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        /* <LoginTextInput text="input use name" Icon={UserIcon} /> */
        <LoginTextInput text="input use name" Icon={<UserIcon />} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

But this code can not be compiled and report a `"expect a string or a class/function, but get: undefined"` error.

I tag the error above, it seems the `Icon` props can not be defined in this code.

**SOLUTION**

Because I use the component UserIcon, so it should be let it changed to `<UserIcon / >`.

Comment: can you try using this `<LoginTextInput text="input use name" pIcon={UserIcon} />` and get this prop accordingly in `LoginTextInput ` like `const { pIcon } = this.props`. let me know if it fix your issue

Comment: It report a error `not found name pIcon, make sure to start component name with a capital letter`.

Comment: instead of using `<Icon />` in your `LoginTextInput` use the prop directly like this `{this.props.pIcon}`

Comment: I find the answer and tag it in my code.